# Fixing function so that I can input multiple words

Tags: r

I'm creating something that computes values for each letter of an input, the input being a letter string such as "back" or "today" or whatever word you can think of. It isn't complete yet but I thought I'd try to see if it can handle more than just a single word input.

This is the code:

```
compute_pos <- function(strg){

#store the middle position of the word
some_input <- nchar(strg)

if(!some_input%%2){

    result0 <- substr(strg, some_input/2, (some_input/2)+1)
}

else{

    odd_input <- median(sequence(some_input))

    result1 <- substr(strg, odd_input, odd_input)

}
#store first letter
split.wLB <- substr(strg, 1, 1)

#store last letter
split.wRB <- substr(strg, nchar(strg), nchar(strg))

matching_left <- letters[(which(split.wLB == letters))]

matching_center <- if ((nchar(strg) %% 2) != 0) {

    letters[(which(result1 == letters))]
}
else{
    result0[(which(result0 == result0))]
}

matching_right <- letters[(which(split.wRB == letters))]


print(paste("Values of the first letter of: ", strg))

#the value of the left most letter from the left most position
print(paste(matching_left,"L", 1))

#get the value of the left most letter from the mid position
if ((nchar(strg) %% 2) != 0) {

    print(paste( matching_left,"M", (.33333*1.00001) - ((odd_input - 1) * .05)))
}
else{
    print(paste( matching_left,"M", (.33333*1.00001) - (median(sequence(some_input)) - 1.5) * .05 ))
}

#get the value of the left most letter from the right most position
print(paste( matching_left,"R", (.33333*1.00001) - ((nchar(strg)- 1) * .05)))

print(paste("Values of the last letter of: ", strg))

#get the value of the right most letter from the left most position
print(paste( matching_right, "L", (.33333*1.00001) - ((nchar(strg)-1) * .05)))

#get the value of the right most letter from the mid most position
if ((nchar(strg) %% 2) != 0) {

    print(paste( matching_right, "M", (.33333*1.00001) - ((odd_input -1) * .05)))
}
else{
    print(paste( matching_right, "M", (.33333*1.00001) - (median(sequence(some_input)) - 1.5) * .05))
}

#get the value of the right most letter from the right most position
print(paste(matching_right, "R", 1))





}
```

when I test it out for a single word it works out fine, so for example if I were to do `compute_pos('back')` the output is :

```
[1] "Values of the first letter of:  back"
[1] "b L 1"
[1] "b M 0.2833333333"
[1] "b R 0.1833333333"
[1] "Values of the last letter of:  back"
[1] "k L 0.1833333333"
[1] "k M 0.2833333333"
[1] "k R 1"
```

However now if I do `x <- c('back', 'today')` and then `compute_pos(x)` I get the following errors:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (!some_input%%2) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if ((nchar(strg)%%2) != 0) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if ((nchar(strg)%%2) != 0) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if ((nchar(strg)%%2) != 0) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How do I fix this so that the function can take as input multiple words?

Comment: Use the `Vectorize` function.

Comment: Well thank you! solved the problem for the current code. Could I ask you something though, I've since added some code, and I am returned this error message `Error in dots[[1L]][[1L]] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable` but only when I do `Vectorize(compute_pos)` and them attempt to use it. From what I've seen it has something to do with a function that already exists within R?

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, I figured out the problem.